# Linear Algebra: Can a 3x3 matrix have no pivots?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that if the second and third row can somehow be manipulated to zero, then the matrix will have a single pivot. However, I'm not so sure about a matrix having no pivots, because that just means the entire matrix is filled with zero. Thank you!

Comment: You are correct. Unless it is a zero matrix, the least dimension should be 1, which gives a pivot